# How to filter/merge/combine this data in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's the code:

```
rowData = [
    [
     '2019-12-10 08:00:00', '2019-12-10 08:00:00', '2019-12-10 08:00:00', '2019-12-10 08:00:00', '2019-12-10 08:00:00', '2018-12-10 08:00:00'
    ],

    [
     '2017-12-10 08:00:00', '2017-12-10 08:00:00', '2017-12-10 08:00:00', '2017-12-10 08:00:00', '2017-12-10 08:00:00', '2017-12-10 08:00:00'
    ],
  ]
```

how to merge this data array in angular.

here's the sample output:

```
[
 '2019-12-10 08:00:00', '2018-12-10 08:00:00', '2017-12-10 08:00:00'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your date to a flatten array with `Array.flat` method, then get unique items from the flatten array.

In sort:

```js
let rowData = [ [ '2019-12-10 08:00:00', '2019-12-10 08:00:00', '2019-12-10 08:00:00', '2019-12-10 08:00:00', '2019-12-10 08:00:00', '2018-12-10 08:00:00' ], [ '2017-12-10 08:00:00', '2017-12-10 08:00:00', '2017-12-10 08:00:00', '2017-12-10 08:00:00', '2017-12-10 08:00:00', '2017-12-10 08:00:00' ], ]
var output = Array.from(new Set(rowData.flat()));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: I try to apply it on my code but it only combine the array it same date